# Combing two referral links into one using filter in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have two referral urls that come from an email campaign and I'd like to combine them under referrals. The links are:

```
links.ssa.gov
links.govdelivery.com
```

So I set a search and replace filter with the following regex. The search string is:

```
.*links\.ssa\.gov.*|.*links\.govdelivery\.com.*
```

and I'd like to replace them with the replace string 'govdelivery_emails'

The two referral links are still showing up though. Is my regex done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking...anytime regex is needed in a filter, an Advanced filter does a better job of producing the desired result than a S&R filter.  There are exceptions, of course, but I will not go into specifics here.

Here are the Advanced filter settings I would use for this scenario:

1) Field A -> Extract A

Field: Campaign Source

Match Pattern:  (links.(ssa.gov|govdelivery.com))$

2) Field B -> Extract B

leave empty

3) Output To -> Constructor

Field: Campaign Source

Output Pattern:  govdelivery_emails

Field A Required: yes

Override Output Field: yes

These filter settings should work for you.